# How to run php script

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I have 7-8 php scripts written which pulls data from remote server and store it into our server. Each script insert/update around 3000-4000 records at a time. When I hit any script from browser it works fine(individual script) but if I try to call all files together by writing header('Location: http://www.example.com/') it gets break. Can anyone suggest me a better way to work with this. Someone suggested me use multi-threading I have not used threading yet so can anyone help me with the better approach/solution. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** your current code doesn't work because `header('Location: example.com')` redirects the browser to `example.com` which means your php script finished running and the browser is now on `example.com`

**Solution 1:**
 if `allow_url_fopen` is "On" in php.ini you can execute them as using:

```
<?php 
   $url1 = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/1.php');
   $url2 = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/2.php');
?>
```

and so on...

**Solution 2:**

```
   function initCURL($url) {
          $curl = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
          $data = curl_exec($curl);
          curl_close($curl);
          return $data;
   }
```

use it as follows:

```
<?php
   $url1 = initCURL('http://www.example.com/1.php');
   $url2 = initCURL('http://www.example.com/2.php');
?>
```

in these examples `$url1` and `$url2` will carry whatever data is returned by the scripts.

Comment: Hey thanks Jaswinder Singh for your help. I will try this code and will let you know. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey Jaswinder Singh Thank you so much. Solution1 worked perfectly.